# What characters ARE allowed when querying a mysql database?

Tags: php, sql, mysql

I have a textarea in a form, when I enter special characters in it, I get an error in mysql. (when submitting the form to a php-file which does the work of inserting into mysql)

I need to know exactly what characters that aren't allowed, or easier would be, exactly what characters thar ARE allowed, so that I could validate the textarea before submitting.

Does anybody know?

I have tried **mysql_real_escape_string()** but didn't help...

NOTE: In the textarea, users are supposed to enter some special chars like these:

```
 + , . ; : - _ space & % ! ? = # * ½ @ / \ [ ] ' " < > £ $ €
```

Probably got them all...

how can I do this?

Thanks

**UDPATE**

My mysql_query :

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO cars_db (description) VALUES ('$ad_text')");
```

**UPDATE**

Mysql error:

```
    You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'a"a!a?aa+a-a_a
a/a\a[a]a}a{a&a%a#a@a¨a^a*a*aa,a.a:a;a|a½a
§a' at line 1
```

Comment: What I've done in the past to simplify all this is create a "sql()" function that wraps the sql escaping function & returns it, whether that is mysql_real_escape_string, or one for a completely different database, so that you can switch out what you use, and yet use a shorter-named function.

Comment: What is your database encoding? It could be that the error is related to a specific character (and you're testing all of them at once).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A database column can technically hold any of those characters. The problem is that you are not escaping them properly in your query.

One way way to do this using [mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/mysql_real_escape_string) is as follows:

```
$sql=sprintf("insert into cars_db (description) values ('%s')",
    mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['description']) );

//execute query and show errors that result...
$result = mysql_query($sql);
if (!$result) {
    die("Oops:<br>$sql<br>".mysql_error());
}
```

Another way is to use a library like PDO or ADODb which makes it easier to use prepared statements with placeholders. Such libraries ensure that data injected into queries is properly escaped.

This is good practice not only because it solves your problem, but it also improves the security of your code, since it becomes harder to perform SQL injection attacks.

Comment: your update doesn't really show how you constructed the $ad_text value

Comment: what do you mean how I constructed it, its just a textarea, where users put in whatever text, and it gets submitted to phpfile, and fetched using the $_POST in php... thats it

Comment: your post says you tried mysql_real_escape_string, but doesn't make it clear how.

Comment: oh, like this: $ad_text=mysql_real_escape_string($ad_text);

Comment: ok, so what error does your code produce? do you display mysql_error() in the event of failure?

Comment: What Paul is trying to aks you is: WHERE IS EXACLTY VALORIZED $ad_text? Somewhere, you should have something like: $ad_text = $_POST['textarea_name'];, and then your query.
Replace your query with: mysql_query("INSERT INTO cars_db (description) VALUES ('".mysql_real_escape_string($ad_text)."')");
 and should be fine... well, maybe not fine, but better. Oh, replace 'textarea_name' with the name of your textarea.

Comment: I got it,,,, I previously used mysql_real_escape_string AFTER the variable was fetched with POST... but changing the code so that it does it at the same time like DaNieL proposed solved it.

Comment: Eh, mysql_real_scape_string DONT return the 'escaped string', people get confising many times ;)

Answer (score 4):

Another way would be to use prepared statements. This makes sure SQL injection isn't possible.

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
$ad_text = mysql_real_escape_string($ad_text);
mysql_query("INSERT INTO cars_db (description) VALUES ('$ad_text')");
```

Read up on mysql_real_escape_string and SQL injection. This is a massive security hole in your application.

http://us.php.net/mysql_real_escape_string

Comment: mysql_real_escape_string does not alter its operand, this code would not work.

Comment: doh! Thank you Mr. Dixon. I've corrected my post, and upvoted yours.

Comment: better :) You might want to lose the extra closing parentheses on the first line though..

Comment: :) Reading this, you'd never guess I've written this code thousands of times.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of escaping characters so as not to trip up your query, why not create a stored procedure with an incoming String parameter.  Just pass the form variable's value (or save it to a string) and pass that to the stored procedure.